# MOSFET Over Heating. So hot it's melting the solder

Tags: mosfet, heat

Alright, continuing with the debugging of my new board tonight I found another issue worse than the one before: My switching MOSFET is getting so hot that I'm getting molten solder.

I replaced the MOSFET with a short circuit just to see if the components sorounding the MOS were the cause of the problem (mostly a big Inductor I have right next to it) but the copper reaches a temperature of 110°F, not enough to melt solder.

This is my schematic:

[image]

As you can see, my V<sub>GS</sub> is around -11V and I'm running 3A through it using an Electronic Load. Based on the datasheet of my [NTD20P06L-D](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NTD20P06L-D.PDF) this thing can do up to 15.5A.

Any ideas of what might be going on?

The only thing I could think of was that the heat on the copper could be increasing R<sub>DS(on)</sub> but at that particular low current it shouldn't be so serious.

I am using the TO-252-3, DPak (2 Leads + Tab) package.

Comment: I separated the PAD from the board and connected it via 18 AWG wire and the melting occurred almost immediately, so it is definitely the part getting super hot.

Comment: Have a look at figure 11 (pg 5 in that datasheet). For an 11 V Vgs, the maximum dc current is more like 5 A than 15. You're still under that, but it's not surprising you need a heat sink.
Also notice notes 1 and 2 on pg 1 of the datasheet. The drain current ratings assume a 1" square pad on your pcb. If you are just using the minimum pad, you should de-rate by about 40% according to the thermal resistance values.
Also, the 15 A rating is an absolute maximum, not a recommended operating condition. If you want your circuit to last, you should de-rate from this to begin with.

Comment: Is this PWM switched or essentially low speed on/off? What switching speed. Gate is driven off by 100l pullup and will a long time to turn off. If occasional that's fine enough. If PWM then you need a gate driver. Very simple driver cct available if needed.

Comment: This is steady state. It remains always on.

Comment: Short the collector and emitter of your transistor, and see what happens. Also (in that state) measure the gate-drain voltage and the source-drain voltage of your FET.

Comment: The key measurement that seems to be missing is the voltage across the MOSFET drain - source.  With this and the current, you can calculate the power dissipation and compare that to the rating in your installed configuration.  You can also calculate the RDSon - if the later is substantially different from the spec, you likely have a drive problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you need a heatsink.

Another thing to check is your gate voltage when you have the FET switched on. If your Gate-Drain voltage is too high, the MOSFET may not be properly biased on, a situation which would generate a lot of heat.

Also, how often is this switching? Is it a steady-state thing, or is this part of a switching supply? If it's a switching supply,  you will also need to look at the rate at which the system switches.

---

Anyways, assuming you have everything biased properly (probably a safe assumption, but measure it anyways):

**R<sub>DS<sub>(on)</sub></sub>** = 130mΩ @ G-D voltage of 5V

So, with 130 mΩ in series with 3A:

$$V = 0.130 * 3$$
$$V = 0.39$$
$$Power = V * A$$
$$Power = 0.39 * 3$$
$$Power = 1.17W$$

So you're going to be dissipating 1.17W of power in the MOSFET, in the best-case situation.
That will get *very* toasty without a heatsink. If you're just running this as a bare TO-220 device, it getting extremely hot isn't too suprising.

---

So, assuming we have a TO-220 in free-air:

> TO-220 junction-to-air thermal to ambient equals 62.5 degree per watt.

[(From here)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16889/1374)

Therefore:

$$Δ°C = 62.5 * 1.17$$

$$Δ°C = 73.125$$
$$Device Temperature °C = 73.125 + Ambient$$
$$Device Temperature °C = 98.125$$

So assuming ideal thermal dissipation on a bare TO-220, it's still going to easily reach ~100°C.
Any environmental factors that further reduce the device's cooling will make it worse.